# "Eu amo mim mesmo" está correto?

Tags: verbos, colocação-pronominal

É muito comum eu ouvir “mim mesmo” quando o objeto é “eu”, assim como “eu amo mim mesmo”. Pelo que eu sei, só se usa “mim” quando preposicionado, como em “eu fiz isso **para** mim”, e não há nenhuma preposição em “eu amo mim mesmo”. O mesmo acontece com *ti*, *si*, *nós*, *vós*; mais raramente com *ele(s)* e *ela(s)*. Está correto isso? Deixo alguns exemplos:

1. “Eu amo mim mesmo” = “Eu me amo”;
2. “Pedem ti mesmo para fazer o *show*” = “Pedem a ti mesmo para fazer o *show*”;
3. “Ele Quebrou si mesmo” = “Ele se quebrou”;
4. “Nós queremos nós mesmos” = “Nós nos queremos”;
5. “Vós pagais vós mesmos” = “Vós vos pagais”;
6. “Os Joões daquela rua sempre arrebentam si mesmos” = “O Joões daquela rua sempre se arrebentam”.

É mais enfático dizer “eles abraçaram si mesmos” do que “eles se abraçaram”.

A minha hipótese é que é omissão da preposição “a”, que pode ser usada para indicar objeto (ex.: “ele quebrou ao vaso”). Assim “Carlos cortou si mesmo com uma faca” = “Carlos cortou a si mesmo com uma faca”.

Comment: Na realidade, também é comum dizer "ele ama si", que, para mim, é obvia omissão da preposição "a".

Comment: amar **a** si mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Nos exemplos indicados há dois erros. Primeiro o [verbo deve ser na voz reflexiva](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/vozes-verbais/) pois o sujeito gramatical é simultaneamente agente e paciente da sua acção, depois tal como a pergunta indica falta a preposição.

1. Eu amo-**me a** mim mesmo.
2. <del>Pedem</del> Pede-**te a** ti mesmo para fazer o show <- Aqui tinha o erro adicional de o verbo estar mal conjugado.
3. Ele quebrou-**se a** si mesmo.
4. Nós queremo-**nos a** nós mesmos.
5. Vós pagais-**vos a** vós mesmos.
6. Os Joões daquela rua sempre arrebentam-**se a** si mesmos.

De resto, os exemplos têm em comum o realce do pronome objecto usando o *"mesmo"*, podia omitir-se no caso da ênclise. Podia-se também trocar a ênclise por próclise sem alterar no essencial os exemplos.

Nisto as gramáticas indicam haver diferenças entre o português de Portugal e do Brasil, não tenho a certeza mas penso os exemplos estarem apesar de tudo errados. Acho um bocado forçado o resultado de omitir a preposição e o pronome em conjunto.

Comment: desculpa, mas "pedem (a) ti mesmo" não é para ter voz reflexiva. Nesse, a ideia é tipo "pedem Elthon John mesmo".

Comment: @Schilive pelo exemplo dado continuo sem perceber a frase. Era melhor mostrar a frase pretendida com as palavras todas (preposição, etc...) As outras frases seguiam todas o mesmo padrão menos essa.

Answer (score 0):

Para a colocação pronominal existem 6 fatores importantes:

1. uso de próclise na presença de um conector de subordinação próximo; que são as conjunções subordinadas, podendo ser elas integrantes, adverbiais e pronome relativo);
2. a presença do termo "não" e seus assemelhados. Ou seja, pronomes indefinidos de valor negativo (nada, ninguém, jamais, nem);
3. próclise é proibida no início da frase;
4. ênclise é proibida em particípio;
5. ênclise é proibida em futuro do presente do indicativo e do pretérito do indicativo;
6. infinitivo sempre aceita ênclise. Porém *não é obrigatório*!

Logo, amar é um verbo intransitivo. Mas que neste caso está com a preposição omitida. Em alguns casos a omissão da preposição não é indicativo de que ela não esteja, ou seja, pode ser um efeito do vício da linguagem oral. Portanto, na oração "Eu amo" não há sentido de finalização, o sujeito da oração faz uma projeção de ação, logo "amar" aqui é um verbo transitivo indireto, pois precisa *amar a* alguma coisa.
Mim é um pronome oblíquo tônico e é sempre precedido de uma preposição, tais como: para, a, de e com. E é usado para substituir substantivos que tem a função de objeto indireto.
Na oração "Eu amo mim mesmo", considerando a transitividade do verbo "amar", e o caráter enfático que o "a" impõe à transitividade do verbo, *mim* está sendo usado de forma correta.

Comment: Marco, bem-vindo ao site. Tens alguma fonte credível que suporte o que afirmas? Várias coisas que dizes vão contra tudo o que eu aprendi. *Amar* é transitivo direto, um dos casos que admite objeto direto preposicionado (vê por exemplo a Gramática do Celso Cunha), e a forma *mim* não dispensa preposição.

Comment: **amar a si mesmo** não tem nada a ver com a sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Amar é um raro caso de verbo que é transitivo e intransitivo ao mesmo tempo. (e eu me lembro como adorei aprender isso na escola)
Pois eu posso simplesmente amar: Eu amo. (intransitivo)
E também posso amar A alguém ou algo, pedindo portanto o uso da preposição. (transitivo direto)
No caso, assim como no exemplo citado na pergunta : "Eu fiz isso a mim mesmo" , o correto é "Eu amo a mim mesmo" pois o verbo está sendo usado na forma transitiva.